# Loading Laravel relationship from a pivot

Tags: laravel, pivot, relation

I am having a problem but am wondering if I am doing things the wrong way.

My situation is this:

- I have a table called "pages" which contains a list of pages on a website.
- Every page can contain many "modules" (Form, Calendar etc). So I have a table called "modules"
- I have a "module_page" pivot table that ties modules to pages
- Finally, a "form" module is generic. There are different types of forms (feedback form, registration forms etc). So I have a table called "forms"

For the purpose of this example, I am interested only in the "Form" module. The individual forms themselves are specific instances of "Form" so I have called them "specifics"

```
pages            modules
+----+--------+  +----+----------+
| id | name   |  | id | name     |
+----+--------+  +----+----------+
| 1  | page a |  | 1  | calendar |
+----+--------+  +----+----------+
| 2  | page b |  | 2  | form     |
+----+--------+  +----+----------+

forms            module_page
+----+--------+  +---------+-----------+-------------+
| id | name   |  | page_id | module_id | specific_id |
+----+--------+  +---------+-----------+-------------+
| 1  | form a |  | 1       | 2         | 1           |
+----+--------+  +---------+-----------+-------------+
| 2  | page b |  | 2       | 2         | 2           |
+----+--------+  +---------+-----------+-------------+
```

My Page model looks like this

**Page.php**

```
public function modules()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Module::class)->withPivot('specific_id')
}
```

when I run `$page = Page::where('id', 1)->with('modules');` I successfully get the following back

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => page a

    [modules] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => form
                    [pivot] => Array
                        (
                            [page_id] => 4
                            [module_id] => 6
                            [specific_id] => 1
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

So far, so good. But what I would like to do now is to include the specific form as a child of a module. So the output would be:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => page a

    [modules] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => form
                    [specific] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [name] => form a
                        )
                    [pivot] => Array
                        (
                            [page_id] => 4
                            [module_id] => 6
                            [specific_id] => 1
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I am having trouble with this, because the specific_id is part of the pivot table and not a part of module. I have tried the following in a 'shut your eyes and hope for the best' attempt, but obviously it didn't work

**Module.php**

```
public function specifics()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Form::class, 'id', 'pivot.specific_id');
}

$page = Page::where('id', 1)->with('modules.specifics');
```

What is the best solution?

Thanks

Comment: You could make separate table `module_specifics`, instead of storing that relationship in pivot table.